# Apache Storm - What is the difference between the Scheme and the MultiScheme interface?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I couldn't find any documentation about the `Scheme` and `MultiScheme` interfaces of Apache Storm. The implementations are here:

- https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/spout

But I don't understand when I should use `Scheme` and when I should use `MultiScheme`. Most example code I found was using implementations of `MultiScheme` and many also used the mysterious `SchemeAsMultiScheme` implementation. 
Can anyone explain what `Scheme`, `MultiScheme` and `SchemeAsMultiScheme` are actually for? Is there a difference between `RawMultiScheme` and `SchemeAsMultiScheme(new RawScheme())`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a decent description on the Storm-Kafka GitHub page (https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka):

"The default RawMultiScheme just takes the byte[] and returns a tuple with byte[] as is. The name of the outputField is "bytes". There are alternative implementations like SchemeAsMultiScheme and KeyValueSchemeAsMultiScheme which can convert the byte[] to String.

There is also an extension of SchemeAsMultiScheme, MessageMetadataSchemeAsMultiScheme, which has an additional deserialize method that accepts the message byte[] in addition to the Partition and offset associated with the message."